# Declaring and Assigning a object some rvalue in the same line

Tags: c++, string, constructor, rvalue

I am trying to replicate the string class function where we can declare and assign a string class object value some rvalue in the same line.

e.g string s1 = "Hello"

But I am trying to do it with integers. My code is like this.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Foo {
    private:
        int a;
    public:
        Foo () {

        }
        explicit Foo(int a) {
            this->a = a;
        }
        Foo(Foo &obj) {
            this->a = obj.a;
        }
        void operator= (int a) {
            cout<<"operator called "<<endl;
            this->a=a;
        }
        void print() {
            cout<<"a is "<<this->a<<endl;
        }
};

int main () {
    Foo obj2 = 10;  // Getting error here (no int to Foo conversion found) 
    obj2.print();
    return 0;
}
```

I understand that removing explicit from my single parameter constructor (i.e making it a converting constructor) would do the trick but I want to keep the ctor as explicit. Is there any way to achieve this? I tried to overload the "=" assignment operator as well but no luck. Please help.

Comment: "but I want to keep the ctor as explicit" Why?

Comment: *"declare and assign a [object] some rvalue in the same line"* -- the correct term to use here is "initialize" as the assignment operator is not used.

Comment: `Foo obj2 = 10;` calls the constructor, not `operator=`. The only way to make it work is to supply a valid constructor (remove explicit).

Comment: @Jodocus No specific reason as such. Just out of curiosity - is it not possible to do it without making the ctor implicit? Is the ctor implicit in the original string class as well?

Comment: `string s1 = "Hello";` no rvalues here.  `"Hello"` is a string literal and is passed to the constructor of `std::string s1` no rvalues are created.

Comment: you should learn that you should initialize your objects not overwrite it. So please use initializer list before you enter the constructor block itself.

Comment: @hacker_panda Yes, I believe it would be [number 5](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string) here.

Comment: Further than that, this is the *point* of the `explicit` keyword. Using `explicit` on a one-arg constructor prevents *this exact* syntax.

Answer (score 1):

Main purpose of declaring constructor `explicit`, according to Bjarne, is to make implicit conversion illegal, e.g.

```
void Bar(Foo a);

Foo obj2 = 10;  // illegal, conversion int to Foo
Bar(10);        // illegal too
```

Instead those should be converted *explicitly*:

```
Foo obj2 = Foo(10);
Bar(Foo(10));
```